# Place UILabel on top of popover controller (in Z-order that is)?

Tags: ios, ipad

My app presents some selections in a popover. I'd like to animate the selection by whizzing a text label from the selection to the cursor. In the image below: If I tap the word "they" I would like for my label to appear with a similar font and the text "they" on top of the popover where "they" is currently displayed, then move towards the cursor. What actually happens is that the label appears below the popover, and doesn't become visible until it has "cleared" the popover.

So: My problem is that the label I use for animation is lower in Z-order than the popover.

This naive approach does NOT work:

```
    [self.view.window bringSubviewToFront:self.animationLabel];
```

Can that be fixed? Should it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIWindow at level Alert works. I doubt anything else does. You live and learn...

Kudos to Noah Witherspoon:
[How to add a view on top of a UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622063/how-to-add-a-view-on-top-of-a-uipopovercontroller)