# How to show a UIView OVER a UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uikit, uipopovercontroller

In my app, I have my main view and when i click a button, a UIPopoverController is shown over my main view (not fullscreen so i still see the view behind) containing a UITableView. When I click one of the tableview cells, I want to show a custom view centered on screen (simple view informing the user that the app is processing) that will fade in and fade out during a specific amount of time.

The problem is that my custom view always appears UNDER the UIPopover...I tried all I can think of, bringSubviewToFront etc...Nothing works... I also tried to wrap my custom view in a UIViewController and use [mainView presentViewController:myCustomView ...] but when I do that the main view disappear

Someone can help?
Thx

Comment: Duplicate of [How to add a view on top of a UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622063/how-to-add-a-view-on-top-of-a-uipopovercontroller)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thx Ole Begemann, this question was indeed a duplicate.
Although, the solution to my problem is not to subclass UIWindow but to add my UIView to the key UIWindow :

```
NSArray * windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
UIWindow* win0 = [windows objectAtIndex:0];

[win0 addSubview:loadingView];
[win0 bringSubviewToFront:loadingWindow];
```