# UISplitViewController - Master popover - Portrait mode: How to custom/remove the border at the very top layer?

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, uipopover

Sorry for the confusing title, but I'm not sure the correct name of the border.

I've created the UISplitViewController that looks like exactly the Mail app in iPad. But my UISplitViewController is not the highest controller in controls hierarchy. 
[image: UISplitViewController nested in UINavigationController]

My problem is that I need a sponsor banner to be displayed under UINavigationBarController but above the UISplitViewController.

As the image, I could have everything in place, but 1 thing, the border of the Master View popover stays on top of the banner.

As my investigation and testing, the border is neither the popover border, nor the view's border. It appears as the UIViewController border???
[image: border that the popover shows?]

How can I change the border's colour or just remove it?
Thanks
-Khang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

There is no way to touch the border, because it's a part on UIViewController.

I realized that the MasterView in portrait mode is a UIPopoverController. It should appear on top of existing content. I tried to insert another view (mask, black UIView to cover the border which was staying on top of the black banner) on top of the popover.

I the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10949989/3509183). Just added the mask view in portrait mode and removed it in landscape mode.

Hope this helps other guys.